# why should we use if( $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")

Tags: php, security

I am watching a video about PHP form submit, it mentions this method

```
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
/* code handle the form date */
}
```

I don't know why we should use that? Can someone explain for me? Thanks!

Comment: It's not a very good video (*tutorial*) if it's not mentioning the "why".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`

contains the request method. It is used to check request method.This variable also says if the request is a '`GET`', '`HEAD`', '`POST`' or '`PUT`' request.

Answer (score 1):

There are various methods of from submission like `POST, GET, PUT, DELETE`.

`$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` holds the name of the method for a form submission. If you want to restrict your form processing only form `POST` type request, then you need to put that check.